Alarm notifications are not displayed on time
Alarms are not triggered on time, notifications are almost always displayed 1-4 minutes after the actual alarm time should be triggered. exact & exactAllowWhileIdle I have applied the results are the same.
I am using android 13 / MIUI 14 for testing.
